# GroupMany equivalent

Tags: c#, linq

I have an `IEnumerable<S>` with `S { T: a; IEnumerable<U> : b}`, and I would like to group this into and `IGrouping<T, U>`, such that each key a is associated with all elements U in any b that is in the same S as that key is tha a of. (It sounds really complicated, but once you imagine the operation I actually want to perform in your head, it becomes pretty clear and seemingly straightforward) What is the proper way to do that? What I currently do is

```
ienum.SelectMany(i => i.b.Select(b => new { i.a, b }))
     .GroupBy(i => i.a, i => i.b);
```

but I can't really say I find that clear or readable in any way shape or form, and not all that DRY either. Surely, there should be a better way?

EDIT: In the comments it is said that a, b and i make for rather unlcear reading. So let's make it a little more concrete. Lets say `S` is now `Office { Manager manager, IEnumerable<Employee> employees}`. That makes the question: Give me an IGrouping of all managers to their employees. That makes the equivalent statement

```
offices.SelectMany(office => office.employees.Select(employee => new { office.manager, employee }))
       .GroupBy(pair => pair.manager, pair => i.employee);
```

I'm not sure if that helps. To me it reads even more unreadable. So, still the same question, how do I make this more readable.

Comment: You could make it more readable by using proper variable names. `i`, `b` and `a` aren't very descriptive.

Comment: I'll make an edit to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ simply works like this. There is not really other way to make it work without actually using `SelectMany` and `GroupBy` in some way.

You should actually be glad, because I have seen many LINQ queries that were many times more complex and harder to understand. To me, that query is still quite simple and expresses the intent clearly. And it is actually easy to follow each step.